# Why are temporary strings created here when returned as const char* ? [Stroustrup's book example]

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand below code from the beginner's book. (edit: 'programming principles and practice using c++' page 1085) I don't quite get why temporary strings are made according to the comments.

```
const char* string_tbl[ ] = { "Mozart", "Grieg", "Haydn", "Chopin" };
const char* f(int i) { return string_tbl[i]; }
void g(string s){}

void h()
{
    const string& r = f(0);  // bind temporary string to r
    g(f(1));                 // make a temporary string and pass it
    string s = f(2);         // initialize s from temporary string
    cout << "f(3): " << f(3) // make a temporary string and pass it
    <<" s: " << s
    << " r: " << r << '\n';
}
```

`f()` returns a pointer to const char, right?

Shouldn't `const string& r = f(0);` assign a 'pointer to char' (in this case of the string literal in the global array) to the reference variable so that the original can be accessed (read-only) with r[] etc?

and `g(f(1));` pass a pointer to `g()` where the `string s` is then initialized with the pointer?

What am I missing? Do const char* always produce a temporary string when it's returned from a function?

Comment: `r` is a `std::string` reference, not a `char *` (ignoring const). How do you "assign 'pointer to char'" to something that's not of that type?

Comment: No, the book is correct. I'm pretty sure that the surrounding text will explain the code.

Comment: Which book is "Stroustrup's book"? He has written more than one.

Comment: Sorry I thought 'beginner's book' would make it clear. It's 'programming principles and practice using c++' page 1085

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't quite get why temporary strings are made according to the comments.

The whole matter is that a `char const*` and a `std::string` are totally different data types.

For comparison:

```
class A { };
class B { };
void f(A a);
void g()
{
    B b;
    f(b); // does not work...
}
```

I'm pretty sure you have encountered that already.

Now let's change class A:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() { }    // default constructor
    A(B b) { } // accepting an instance of B
};
```

Now, you can do:

```
B b;
f(A(b)); // create a TEMPORARY A from B; you need it, as f ONLY accepts an A!
f(b);    // again, create a temporary just as before - this time IMPLICITLY
```

You can disallow implicitly creating A from B by making the constructor *explicit*:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() { }
    explicit A(B b) { } // now A cannot be created implicitly any more
};

B b;
//f(b);  // now is not accepted by compiler any more
f(A(b)); // this still works, of course
```

Exactly the same with `std::string`: It has a non-explicit constructor accepting `char const*`...

Answer (score 1):

There is a implicit conversion, the code

```
string s = f(2);
```

is equal to

```
string s = string(f(2));
```